# Deployed application picking Universal time Instead of Local time on AWS Server

Tags: java, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-lightsail, amazon-linux

Currently, My AWS instance showing below time

```
timedatectl status
            **Local time:** Thu 2019-12-26 19:41:51 IST
            Universal time: Thu 2019-12-26 14:11:51 UTC
            RTC time: Thu 2019-12-26 14:11:51
            Time zone: Asia/Kolkata (IST, +0530)
       System clock synchronized: yes
       systemd-timesyncd.service active: yes
       RTC in local TZ: no
```

Pojo

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "hotel_booking")
public class Booking implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Id
    private Integer version;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "ota_reference_no", nullable = false)
    private String referenceNo;

    @Column(name = "guest_name")
    private String guestName;

    @Column(name = "created_date", columnDefinition = "timestamp", nullable = false)
    private LocalDateTime createdDate;

    @Column(name = "modified_date", columnDefinition = "timestamp")
    private LocalDateTime modifiedDate;
```

======

Once persist createdDate filed picking Universal time but required is, **Local time**.

The same getting expected result in localhost:

The database uses: **Postgres** (i.e. installed locally on the AWS instance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do yourself a favor if this is (or will become) a real application, and persist any actual points on the timeline (or real moments) **always** in `UTC` — you can actually get this straight in your application using the `Instant` type. Down the line, you can use `ZonedDateTime` (or `LocalDateTime`, but this one is tricky) to "translate" the values accordingly before exposing it to the user-agents — or for any other operation(s) you might be doing that could be time zone sensitive.

> By the way, the reason you are getting the `Universal time` instead of `Local time` it is because the Java Virtual Machine, the application, the framework you are using for persistence (or a combination) is/are set in such way, either by default, or because somewhere in the application there is a setting like this: `-Duser.timezone=UTC`. If it's the application, it might be `ZoneOffset.UTC` or `TimeZone.setDefault(...)`, but these are unlikely as you would need to do this programmatically. Execute a `System.out.println(ZoneId.systemDefault())`, it should yield `UTC` (or something around those lines).

Comment: Thanks, working fine, the application was using UTC